# Compare columns and show unequal rows in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I have a dataset where I want to check two columns if they have the same values and if there are any unequal rows to show them.

```
(inte_s['CA']==inte_s['CI']).all()
```

which returns

```
False
```

I tried also:

```
inte_s['CA][~inte_s['CA'].isin(inte_s['CI'])]
```

but doesn't work.

How to show the unequal values?

Comment: `inte_s[inte_s['CA'] != inte_s['CI']]`?

Comment: unbelievable haha

Comment: You should read over the [Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html), won't take long and will help a lot!

Comment: I have read it in the past but I simply couldn't think of this right now.